# How to get unique rows by column value using linq

Tags: linq

I have values in table format

```
   IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Data>> tableResult=new IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Data>>();
   //below line doesn't work     
   tableResult = tableResult.Distinct(row => row("ID"));
```

tableResult contains value in table format, say(Dummy example). Record I am getting is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Data>>` is not table. Dont expect you will get column name

```
ID Name     Designation
 1 Sam      Engg
 3 Mos      Doc
 3 Peter    Driver
 4 Bob      Builder
```

Expected result is : How to get unique rows by ID using linq.

```
     ID Name     Designation
     1 Sam      Engg
     3 Mos      Doc        
     4 Bob      Builder
```

Comment: Can you explain why `3 Mos      Doc` and not `3 Peter    Driver` is displayed for id=3, could it be the other way around, or do you have a rule for selecting which row?

Comment: Show the type `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by id and select the first item in each ID group.
Assuming your ID column is the first element in the inner `IEnumerable`:

```
tableResult.GroupBy(x => x.First()).Select(x => x.First());
```

If you want to have a more specific definition of what row you want to display when you have duplicate ID:s you replace `.Select(x => x.First())` with `.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Skip(n).First()).First())` where n is the column number to sort on.

Comment: its not table, so you will not get column name as ID